# Adding COMPLETELY FREE full text search capability to Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, full-text-search, google-cloud-firestore

My client has a project based on Firebase. They want me to add some functionalities to its core, and make necessary changes on client applications. One of the new functionalities requested is text-based search on Firestore documents. **But this solution should be totally free.**

According to [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search) I may use [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com) or [ElasticSerach](https://www.elastic.co) or an equivalent of these. But to use these services I should pay for the service, or rent a Google Cloud Platform or AWS deployment, or a standard dedicated server, and all of these solutions requires periodical payments.

So, in the end, I've 2 solutions.

**1. Search on Client**

Query all documents and perform the search on them.

**2. Use `Cloud Functions`**

Query all documents in cloud functions and return the search result.

Both approaches will increase the Firebase usage. This might cause limit excess and unintended invoices.

My question is, Is there any free search service? Do you have a better idea than mines? If you don't; which approach is better?

Comment: Both of your questions have an answer in the duplicate.